# Debug python function call from an imported module

Tags: python, debugging, scikit-learn

I would like to know what functions are called when I run a cross-validation with scikit learn library similar to the code below:

```py
scores = cross_val_score(estimator=clf,
                             X=X_train,
                             y=y_train,
                             cv=10,
                             scoring='roc_auc')
```

In particular, I would like to understand what predict function is called from within scikit learn.

Comment: with inspect module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the inspect modules

```
# import required modules
import inspect
  
def fun(a,b):
    # product of 
    # two numbers
    return a*b
  
# use getsource()
print(inspect.getsource(fun))
```

output is like below

> def fun(a,b):
> product of
> two numbers
> return a*b

sourc : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inspect-module-in-python/